# Trouble matching punctuation using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I am working on converting data into XML format. One of the XML constraints is that:

Tag names cannot contain any of the characters !"#$%&'()*+,/;<=>?@[]^`{|}~, nor a space character, and cannot begin with "-", ".", or a numeric digit.

I am trying to catch these errors before creating the tags, and am having trouble using regex to match anything containing any of those characters.

I would love to be able to use '[:punct:]' but since a few punctuation characters are allowed, I cannot.

The regex I have tried:

```
'[!"#$%&\'()*+,/;<=>?@[\\]^`\\{|\\}~ ]'
```

R code:

```
practice <- c("T[K","T!K","T\"K","T#K","T$K","T%K","T&K","T'K","T(K",  "T)K","T*K","T+K","T,K","T/K","T;K","T<K","T=K","T>K","T?K","T@K",  "T[K","T\\K","T]K","T^K","T`K","T{K","T|K","T}K","T~K","T]K")

grepl(pattern = '[!"#$%&\'()*+,/;<=>?@[\\]^`\\{|\\}~]', practice)
```

I expected the results to be all TRUE.

Actual Results:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I am assuming I am messing up with the syntax of the backslash escapes or understanding of the []. However, I have been doing research and am still having trouble figuring out what is wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `grepl("[[:punct:][:space:]]", practice)`. See the named classes of characters in `?regex`.

Comment: Hey Rui, Unfortunately, I can't use [:punct:] because both '.' and '-' are allowed. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need more escapes. Here I've escaped every special regex character, and reordered the pattern so that they are in the same order as in `practice`. Note that you have `]` appear twice in `practice`; I removed it and added examples with `_` and `.` since you said those were allowed and I can show they are correctly not matched.

Remember than `\` is escape in R strings, and then it is also escape in regular expressions, so you need to `\\` escape special characters in regex. In other words, the supplied *string* `\\$` is seen as the *pattern* `\$` which means a *literal* `$` instead of the end of the string. This also means that you need `\\\\` for a literal `\`...

```r
practice <- c("T.K","T_K","T[K","T!K","T\"K","T#K","T$K","T%K","T&K","T'K","T(K",  "T)K","T*K","T+K","T,K","T/K","T;K","T<K","T=K","T>K","T?K","T@K","T[K","T\\K","T]K","T^K","T`K","T{K","T|K","T}K","T~K")

stringr::str_detect(practice, "[\\[\\!\"#\\$%&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,/;<=>\\?@\\[\\\\\\]\\^`\\{\\|\\}~]")
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [23]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
grepl("[\\[\\!\"#\\$%&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,/;<=>\\?@\\[\\\\\\]\\^`\\{\\|\\}~]", practice, perl = TRUE)
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [23]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Calum, Thank you I really appreciate your help. I was getting confused with the double escapes. That works perfectly